# Running HTC rom on emulator

Tags: android, rom, htc-hero

I have came across some weird behavior while using camera in my app.

I am clicking picture from camera and then uploading it to server. I didn't mention in my code that device should save the pic first, it works well in samsung, nexus BUT on **running it on HTC phones it saves the picture in gallery**, i guess its the default camera action for htc. I don't want to save my pic. yes of course I can delete it in code.

My question is, is there any way to run HTC rom on emulator, since i don't have any HTC device to test my app? Or if someone have system.img file for HTC hero ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to run the htc rom in emulator. You have to user real device for testing. Even for testing [Open Sense API](https://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/opensense-overview), You have to use real device for testing.

Comment: We can run Cyanogen's mod rom on emulator all we need is system.img file.
[Here is the link](http://www.modaco.com/topic/289928-testing-getting-an-emulator-up-and-running-a-full-rom-with-the-market-etc)

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2450045 you can dump the system partition by using this method, but i am not sure it will work or not

Answer (score 0):

You can try to test your app on Genymotion emulator. It has HTC One image, maybe it helps you